# Why does Cassidy of Preacher destroy the vampire he meets in "Cassidy: Blood and Whiskey"

Tags: vertigo-comics, preacher

In "Cassidy: Blood and Whiskey" Cassidy meets another vampire (the only other one he meets besides for the "hag" that turns him into one himself). After spending time with this other vampire Cassidy comes to despise him and destroys him. I never really understood what it was that brought Cassidy to do this, it always seemed an overreaction.

Any explanations for why Cassidy kills the other vampire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the other vampire, whose name is Eccarius, had a thing for killing people. Cassidy didn't mind getting his need of blood from whatever bled (animal or human), but the former did kill a lot of people to satisfy his need. Cassidy was 100% against that; and also, Eccarius lied to Cassidy about that fact.

[image]

When Cassidy finds out, he is pissed.

[image]
[image]

That's why he hits his head with a cross

[image]

and then ties him up in the sun to die

[image]

Comment: I think when I originally read this some years back I got confused when reading the middle panel on the second page (it's what they always want..."). Your explanation really cleared this up for me, thanks.

Comment: If you remember, Eccarius had a following of morons that wanted to be turned to vamprires and begged him to do it. But, when he actually did it, he killed them

Comment: That's what Eccarius is referring to in that panel.

Comment: I must have thought at the time that they (his followers) were obsessed with death and wanted him to kill them (the romantic idea of being food for a vampire or some crap like that). After re-reading (just now) I realize that they wanted him to turn them into vampires and he betrayed them and killed them instead.

Comment: When I read it, years back, I saw it as being as much about Cassidy seeing too much of who he is in Eccarius, being a bit of a casual killer himself, and the cross through the head was a way of physically exorcising those demons.

Comment: @SeanDuggan This might be the case, but I based my answer mostly on the 6th panel of the first pic I posted -> `no need for killin'`

Comment: {nods} Which seems to be the case for feeding. Outside of that, he has no problem killing whoever he feels needs killed. Which, admittedly, seems to be a default attitude in the books.